# a scrap of , a spot of and a trace of

Tags: meaning, word-choice

we got into **a spot of** bother with the police

Question: Can I use **'a scrap of'** and **'a trace of'** in lieu of **'a spot of'** . WHy?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

**A spot of bother** is an expression, meaning a little trouble, although the expression is often used ironically to mean a lot of trouble.

**A scrap of.....** (or a few scraps of) is generally, but not necessarily, used for food, indicating a very small amount.

A scrap - without the preposition - can also refer to a fight.

**A trace of....** is most often used in reporting tiny amounts of a substance, especially those found on clothes or in medicines, compounds, food recipes and so on.

These distinctions are typical rather than required but, regarding your query, to write **a scrap/trace of bother** would not be idiomatic.